# Gremlin Python shortest path between two nodes

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph, gremlinpython

How do we find shortest path between two nodes using `gremlin-python`?

The example given for gremlin [here](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#shortest-path) shows the following `gremlin` query

```
g.V(1).repeat(out().simplePath()).until(hasId(5)).path().
       group().by(count(local)).next()
```

How can I convert this to an equivalent `gremlin-python` query, given that the source and destination node labels are known?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Gremlin query becomes

```java
g.V().hasLabel(<label1>).
      repeat(out().simplePath()).
      until(hasLabel(<label2>)).
      path().
      group().
        by(count(local)).
      next()
```

The `group...by` is not completely needed as the paths returned will be in shortest path order (by depth) i.e. BFS, unless some other weights are used ti find and order them.

In "fully qualified" Gremlin Python (which is not needed if you import the statics etc.) the query becomes:

```py
result = (g.V().hasLabel('label1').
            repeat(__.out().simplePath()).
            until(__.hasLabel('label2')).
            path().
            group().
              by(__.count(Scope.local)).
            next())
```

Comment: Thank you! The first query returns a `GraphTraversal` object, it there a simple way to find the number of nodes and edges in that? It seems `.to_list()` throws errors on the object not being callable.

Comment: The first query in the answer or the one in the question? When using Python, that "object not callable" error, almost always means you have a collision with a Python reserved word.

Comment: The first query in your answer, when `to_list()` is appended at the end, gives `TypeError: 'GraphTraversal' object is not callable`

Comment: It's `toList()` not `to_list()` and it will replace the `next()`

Comment: When using this query on larger graphs the following error is obtained:
`GremlinServerError: 598: A timeout occurred during traversal evaluation of [RequestMessage{, requestId=cc2be6b9-03aa-438c-b960-4491fc969202, op='bytecode', processor='traversal', args={gremlin=[[withStrategies(OptionsStrategy)], [V(), hasLabel(label1), repeat([[], [out(), simplePath()]]), until([[], [hasLabel(label2)]]), path(), group(), by([[], [count(local)]])]], aliases={g=g}, scriptEvaluationTimeout=20}}] - consider increasing the limit given to evaluationTimeout`

Comment: Any query may timeout if it cannot process all of the data it needs to within the current time limit (which can be increased). How much data is the query needing to touch?